# weekly calender table in oracle to update alternative week flag & date

Tags: oracle

I'm creating a table to populate a weekly calendar table and my requirement is to update `wk_start_date` as every week sunday and populate the `pr_wk_flag` as `Y` every two weeks and 
`beg dt` & `end dt` would be from two weeks before Thursday to current Wednesday

Like below, How to populate in oracle plsql

```
Wk_start_date  pr_wk_flag  beg dt        end dt 
2/9/2014       Y           1/30/2014     2/12/2014
2/16/2014      N           NULL          NULL
2/23/2014      Y           2/13/2014     2/26/2014
3/2/2014       N           NULL          NULL
3/9/2014       Y           2/27/2014     3/12/2014
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
select wk_start_dt, pr_wk_flag,
  case when pr_wk_flag = 'Y' then wk_start_dt - 10 end as beg_dt,
  case when pr_wk_flag = 'Y' then wk_start_dt + 3 end as end_dt
from (
  select next_day(date '2014-02-01' + (7 * level), 'SUN') as wk_start_dt,
    decode(mod(level, 2), 1, 'Y', 'N') as pr_wk_flag
  from dual
  connect by level <= 6
);
```

The inner query is a common way to generate a sequence of values. Adjust the start date and the number of iterations to change the range of week-starts generated, and if necessary to flip the flag value. The `SUN` argument to [the `next_day` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions106.htm) has to be in your local session language, so change that to something suitable if you're not using English. As a one-off insert I don't think the NLS-sensitivity is an issue in this case.

The outer query just uses the flag to decide whether to calculate the other two dates, or leave them null.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25292) demo.

Answer (score 0):

There you have for all 2014 year

```
SELECT dates+(8- to_char(TRUNC (TRUNC (dates, 'w'), 'YEAR'),'d')) wk_start_date,
       DECODE (MOD (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dates, 'w')), 2), 0, 'Y', 'N')
           pr_wk_flag,
       DECODE (MOD (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dates, 'w')), 2),
               0, dates + 5 - 17,
               NULL)
           pr_wk_flag,
       DECODE (MOD (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dates, 'w')), 2), 0, dates + 3, NULL)
           end_dt

  FROM (SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * (ROWNUM - 1) dates

          FROM dba_tables
         WHERE TRUNC (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + 7 * (ROWNUM - 1), 'YEAR') =

                   TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YEAR'))
ORDER BY wk_start_date ASC
```

Comment: You need to get the first Sunday in January rather than the 1st day of the year which is what TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') is returning. Plus the use of dba_tables to get a row count makes me cringe :)